# Chainbridge-added in substrate-relaychain

Tags: substrate-node-template, chainbridge

I tried to add Chain bridge and example to our existing substrate `relay-chain`, but I got an error during this import

> (use sp_io::hashing::blake2_128;)

Please let me know how to add this import . I have also attached a screenshot to this post.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Can you share the Cargo.toml?

Answer (score 1):

you can run `cargo update` for find and remove old packages and update that to new version . i faced this problem and it fixed by this command .

Answer (score -1):

It appears that there might be a duplicate dependency in your cargo.toml file, or you might have overlooked adding a dependency to your std. Could you kindly provide the link to your code so that we can investigate the cargo toml?

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Please check the above answer from the post I have posted because in the comment section I am not able to upload the screenshot.

Answer (score -2):

Hi Thanks for your response ,

**The below file is my cargo.toml code inside the runtime folder please check and let me know here.I want to add this line in inside the lib.rs file `(use sp_io::hashing::blake2_128;)`**

```
name = "node-template-runtime"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
description = "A fresh FRAME-based Substrate node, ready for hacking."
authors = ["Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>"]
homepage = "https://substrate.io/"
edition = "2021"
license = "MIT-0"
publish = false
syn = "1.0.94"
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.6.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.5.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
pallet-aura = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-balances = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-grandpa = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-sudo = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

frame-try-runtime = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-timestamp = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-transaction-payment = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-executive = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-block-builder = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-consensus-aura = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-consensus-grandpa = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-core = { version = "21.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-inherents = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-offchain = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-runtime = { version = "24.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-session = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-std = { version = "8.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-transaction-pool = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-version = { version = "22.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-io = {version = "2.0.0",default-features = false }

# Used for the node template's RPCs
frame-system-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

# Used for runtime benchmarking
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-system-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

# Local Dependencies
pallet-template = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../pallets/template" }

[dependencies.chainbridge]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-substrate'
package = 'chainbridge'
tag = 'v1.3.0'

[build-dependencies]
substrate-wasm-builder = { version = "5.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "sp-io/std",
    "frame-try-runtime?/std",
    "frame-system-benchmarking?/std",
    "frame-benchmarking?/std",
    "codec/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "frame-executive/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "frame-try-runtime/std",
    "pallet-aura/std",
    "pallet-balances/std",
    "pallet-grandpa/std",
    "pallet-sudo/std",
    "pallet-template/std",
    "pallet-timestamp/std",
    "pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "pallet-transaction-payment/std",
    "sp-api/std",
    "sp-block-builder/std",
    "sp-consensus-aura/std",
    "sp-consensus-grandpa/std",
    "sp-core/std",
    "sp-inherents/std",
    "sp-offchain/std",
    "sp-runtime/std",
    "sp-session/std",
    "sp-std/std",
    "sp-transaction-pool/std",
    "sp-version/std",
    "substrate-wasm-builder",   
    "chainbridge/std",
    
]
runtime-benchmarks = [
    "frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-support/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-system-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-system/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-balances/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-grandpa/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-sudo/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-template/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-timestamp/runtime-benchmarks",
    "sp-runtime/runtime-benchmarks",
]
try-runtime = [
    "frame-try-runtime/try-runtime",
    "frame-executive/try-runtime",
    "frame-system/try-runtime",
    "frame-support/try-runtime",
    "pallet-aura/try-runtime",
    "pallet-balances/try-runtime",
    "pallet-grandpa/try-runtime",
    "pallet-sudo/try-runtime",
    "pallet-template/try-runtime",
    "pallet-timestamp/try-runtime",
    "pallet-transaction-payment/try-runtime",
]
```

[image]